# Play Compilation time is too high

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am using the Play framework for my development. Each time when I compile, it takes a lot of time. Here's what the console outputs while compiling:

`[info] Compiling 23 Scala sources and 2824 Java sources to E:\Project\Integrity_ Dev\target\scala-2.11\classes...`

It takes at least 45 minutes for compilation to complete. How can I reduce this?

Comment: Well, there are a few obvious questions: the java-sources shouldn't recompile every time you compile the entire project. I could only think of you modifying either the entire source-code or the output-folder as a reason for this - or probably a broken compiler. But why not simply package the java-sources into a `.jar` and use them as library, since that's what they apparently are.

Comment: Were you cleaning your project before compiling? Using activator clean will remove all compile sources. So, when activator compile it will compile all the java and scala sources.

Comment: Thank you @Paul for your reply. But my worry is for 3000 java files it is consuming 45 Min. Ya your are correct when I am changing in single file, it is compiling only that single file. But for single file it is consuming 3 to 5 Mins. Where before play we used Servers like JBoss and build tools like Maven. Which will not take more 5 mins for entire compiling. So is there any optimising way to reduce the compilation time on complete.

Comment: @mani modern compilers - well, any compiler that is younger than me and even quite a bit older - will only recompile, if the source-code is newer than the compiled file. So obviously the compiler can't find the compiled files, since it wouldn't recompile them otherwise. One option to avoid this for sure would be to build a jar-lib and simply include that into your project. Compile once and reuse every time. Or simply make sure you don't clean the project every time, to ensure the compiler doesn't have to recompile the java-files.

Comment: Thank you Paul. But can you please give a line of idea that how to generate as a jar each time while I am compiling and where to drop it in Play. Sorry if this is basic.

Comment: @mani the idea behind the jar-file is that you **don't** build it everytime, but instead build it once, include it into your project and from that point on reuse the same `jar`-file every time.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CompilationSpeed#Improving-Compilation-Times)? It suggests (among other things) to modularize the code. That is, you can create a sub project for for instance your java code. But then again, in case you're not going to modify the java at all, a jar should help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the most likely reason for this is that you by accident clean the build-directory for the java-files each time you recompile your project. You should check the build-script/configuration of your project.

Modern compilers - modern is rather broad here, in fact that's a pretty old feature - only recompile source code, if they can't find the compiled file, or the compiled file is older than the source code. So the simplest approach would be to exclude the build-folder for the java-code from cleaning or from the entire compilation-process at all except including it into the resulting build, if possible.

If you prefer, you can build a `.jar` from the `.class`-files and include that into your project. There's a manifold of possibilities to create `.jar`-files, including maven, ant, whatever IDE you use, etc.. The most generic one would be to build them via [commandline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html).

A simpler way to solve this would probably be a maven-build though, that directly retrieves the files and builds them.